# Firebase - how to get email verify working on signup

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Firebase - how to get email verify working on signup

Im looking for a tutorial on this.

So I can follow steps.

When register, send email verify before user granted access

Comment: I think this is now possible with the new firebase console

Comment: I have same Q - I really hope the Firebase team reply. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729486/firebase-email-verification-workflow